# How to create a date with "as.Date" from 3 different vectors (day, month, years)?

Tags: r, vector, as.date

I have 3 different vectors including data of days, months and years. I would like to merge these 3 into one and add it to a new column of my data frame. I tried to use "as.Date" to merge these 3 vectors but it won't work...

Could you help me? :)

Here is my code:

```
Day<- substr(x = my_meteo_charleroi$Local.Time, start = 1, stop =2 )
Month<- substr(x = my_meteo_charleroi$Local.Time, start = 4, stop =5 )
Year<- substr(x = my_meteo_charleroi$Local.Time, start = 7, stop =10 )

my_date<- as.Date(c(Day, Month, Year), format = c("%d, %m, %y"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close already, just two modifications needed.

Both arguments to `as.Date()` should be strings here, not vectors.

```
as.Date(paste(Day, Month, Year, sep = "-"), format = '%d-%m-%y')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working but I don't know why it doesn't use the format I asked (DMY). it is still in "YMD"

Comment: The format you specify in `as.Date()` is the format of the input data. The YMD format is the standard display format for dates in R as it is unambiguous. To change the way the date is displayed you can use `format()` on the date.

Comment: Thank you again. You are wizard :)

Comment: You are welcome, please upvote/ mark as correct answer, if this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
Day <- c(10,11,12)
Month <- c(11,11,12)
Year <- c(2019,2020,2020)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
tibble(Day, Month, Year) %>% 
mutate(my_date = paste(Day, Month, Year, sep = '-')) %>% 
mutate(my_date = as.Date(my_date, format = '%d-%m-%Y', origin = '1970-01-01')) %>% 
pull(my_date)
[1] "2019-11-10" "2020-11-11" "2020-12-12"
```

Dataframe with my_date column looks like this:

```
tibble(Day, Month, Year) %>% mutate(my_date = paste(Day, Month, Year, sep = '-')) %>% 
   mutate(my_date = as.Date(my_date, format = '%d-%m-%Y', origin = '1970-01-01'))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
    Day Month  Year my_date   
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <date>    
1    10    11  2019 2019-11-10
2    11    11  2020 2020-11-11
3    12    12  2020 2020-12-12
```